# Should I enable Google Auth login by default for my users?

Tags: oauth

I have implemented Google login (OAuth2) login on my website. It matches users by e-mail, i.e. if your e-mail is the same in Google as in our system, and you have Google Auth enabled on my website, you are logged in.

**Should I enable it for everyone by default**? I want to do it on the assumption someone controls Google account, they control the associated e-mail account, and therefore they already have access to the user account on my website (since I implement password reset by e-mail).

Are there any security implications that I should be aware of?

Comment: I really don't see a security compromise per say. Really the only vulnerability would be unauthorized access by 3rd party. 

Possible cookie hijacking? Make sure your site is compliant with security standards.

Comment: This would allow Google (or someone having compromised Google) to impersonate any of your users. I'd say this is a really bad idea unless users explicitly enable it during registration.

Answer (score 1):

**oAuth is not an authentication mechanism**. It handles authorization to access resources (usually an API).

From [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749):

> The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party
> application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service, either on
> behalf of a resource owner by orchestrating an approval interaction
> between the resource owner and the HTTP service, or by allowing the
> third-party application to obtain access on its own behalf.

It is however also used by some as a way to authenticate users. You must trust that service because it has the keys to **your** resources (as opposed to allowing you to access **their** resources, with the agreement of **their** user - which is what oAuth is for)

Wikipedia [points out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth#OpenID_vs._pseudo-authentication_using_OAuth) the differences between oAuth and OpenID (which is an authentication protocol).